# QItemSelectionModel::setCurrentIndex doesn't work on opening

Tags: qt, qtreeview

My code:

```
void TreeModel::selectIndex(QModelIndex ix) {
  if (!ix.isValid()) return;
  qDebug() << "name1" << ix.data();
  tree->selectionModel()->clear();
  tree->setExpanded(ix.parent(), true);
  tree->selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex(ix, QItemSelectionModel::SelectCurrent);
  tree->scrollTo(ix);
}
```

This snippet runs ok after deleting/inserting nodes. But when I try to select the remembered node from previous session in QMainWindow::showEvent the result is:

```
name1 QVariant(QString, "Highlight elements") 
The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\Home\develop\qt\arm\designer\Designer exited with code -1073741819
```

without `tree->selectionModel()->setCurrentIndex(ix, QItemSelectionModel::SelectCurrent);` works well, but I do need to select this item.

Thank you very much in advance!

debugger log:

```
>~"\nProgram received signal "
>~"SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.\n"
>~"0x00438290 in QVariant::Private::Private (this="
>&"warning: (Internal error: pc 0x0 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)\n"
 (Internal error: pc 0x0 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)
>&"\n"
>~"0x0) at ../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/mingw47_32/include/QtCore/qvariant.h:367\n"
>~"367\t        inline Private(): type(Invalid), is_shared(false), is_null(true)\n"

>~"data=[{iname=\"local.node\",name=\"node\",addr=\"0x14384220\",addr=\"0x14384220\",numchild=\"9\",origaddr=\"0x28d86c\",type=\"DNode\",value=\"{...}\",},{iname=\"local.this\",name=\"this\",addr=\"0x14341820\",addr=\"0x14341820\",numchild=\"5\",origaddr=\"0x28d890\",type=\"TreeModel\",value=\"{...}\",},{iname=\"local.index\",name=\"index\",addr=\"0x28dba8\",numchild=\"0\",type=\"QModelIndex &\",value=\"(invalid)\",},{iname=\"local.role\",name=\"role\",addr=\"0x28d898\",numchild=\"0\",type=\"int\",value=\"1\",},],typeinfo=[{name=\"aW50\",size=\"4\"}{name=\"Y29uc3QgUU1vZGVsSW5kZXggJg==\",size=\"4\"}{name=\"RE5vZGUgKg==\",size=\"4\"}{name=\"RE5vZGU=\",size=\"36\"}]\n"
>2390^done
dDISCARDING JUNK AT BEGIN OF RESPONSE: 
dProgram received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
d0x00438290 in QVariant::Private::Private (this=0x0) at ../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/mingw47_32/include/QtCore/qvariant.h:367
d367            inline Private(): type(Invalid), is_shared(false), is_null(true)
 <Rebuild Watchmodel 243>
sFinished retrieving data
```

Comment: Where exactly does it crash? Run it in a debugger.

Comment: in setCurrentIndex without it works. I do use debugger certanly.

Comment: If you run a debugger, then show us the backtrace.

Comment: It gives the message `The inferior stopped because it received asignal from the Operating System. SIGSEGV...`

Comment: That's not a backtrace. A backtrace will show exactly in which line of Qt's source code the crash happens.

Comment: Another issue: this code is badly organized. The model is not supposed to hold explicit references to the view (unless it's a view model - maybe). Remember that a model can have *zero or more* views attached to it. This code logically belongs in a member of some widget that holds the view, or in a subclassed view itself.

Comment: I agree "this code is badly organized" but mainly because of long experiments. Please, could you tell me how to get backtrace from qt creator/gdb?

Comment: In creator, one of the panes shows you the call stack/backtrace. In gdb, type "bt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Qt bug. The only way out:

```
void MainWindow::showEvent(QShowEvent *event) {
  QMainWindow::showEvent(event);
  QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(selectLastNode()));
}
```

Comment: I know it's an old post, but could you provide link to the QTBUG?

Answer (score 0):

1. Does `tree->selectionModel()` return a non-null pointer?
2. How do you "remember" the selected items across application restarts?
3. It is always an error for a model's client (anything that uses a model) to retain a `QModelIndex` after the model's *structure* was changed. Structural changes are any changes that add or remove items in the model. The `isValid` method does *not* detect this issue. Think of model indices as you would of standard C++ library iterators - they also become invalid when you add/remove items from a container.

   I don't know how you implement your model, but if you subclass/reuse any of the standard Qt models, this limitation also applies to your own use of the indices.

   The indices that survive structural changes are called persistent indices. You should use them instead, if you need such functionality.